# How to reorder an array of objects using other array that has index and returns the new ordered array

Tags: javascript, arrays

What I want exactly is a function that we can pass two arrays, one the original array of objects with specific order, and the other is an array of objects that has the new target index so the function will return the original array to new order based on the indexes

For example :
this is how the original array will look like

```
const columns=[
      {

        field: "name",
        type: "action",
        width: settings.defaultColumnWidth,
      },
      {
        field: "country",
        type: "action",
        width: settings.defaultColumnWidth,
      
      },
      {
        field: "phone",
        type: "action",
        width: settings.defaultColumnWidth,            
      },
      {
        field: "email",
        type: "action",
        width: settings.defaultColumnWidth,
        
      },
    ]
```

And the other array that have objects with fields name and the target index to be ordered

```
const newOrder = [
  {
    field: "country"
    oldIndex: 1
    targetIndex: 2
  },
]
```

So the new array that should be returned from the function will be like this

```
  const columns=[
  {

    field: "name",
    type: "action",
    width: settings.defaultColumnWidth,
  },
  {
    field: "phone",
    type: "action",
    width: settings.defaultColumnWidth,            
  },
  {
    field: "country",
    type: "action",
    width: settings.defaultColumnWidth,

  },
  {
    field: "email",
    type: "action",
    width: settings.defaultColumnWidth,

  },
]
```

I hope my question is clear, thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Nothing react related in your question. Where is your attempt to solve it?

Comment: @mplungjan I am happy you asked, the thing is I am using DataGridPro table of mui and there is this prop func onColumnOrderChange when I reorder the columns its return an object with the new order of that specific column, now I want to save the new order because when refresh the order of the columns return as previous, I came up with this solution

Comment: @mplungjan There is already another question about this, but its not answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there won't be too much contradiction, I think `splice` and such should work.

```js
var settings = {
  defaultColumnWidth: 12
}

const columns = [{
    field: "name",
    type: "action",
    width: settings.defaultColumnWidth
  },
  {
    field: "country",
    type: "action",
    width: settings.defaultColumnWidth
  },
  {
    field: "phone",
    type: "action",
    width: settings.defaultColumnWidth
  },
  {
    field: "email",
    type: "action",
    width: settings.defaultColumnWidth
  }
]

const newOrder = [{
    field: "country",
    oldIndex: 1,
    targetIndex: 2
  }
];



newOrder.forEach(function(item) {
  var field = item.field
  var targetIndex = item.targetIndex
  for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
    var column = columns[i];
    if (column.field == field) {
      var elem = columns.splice(i, 1)[0];
      columns.splice(targetIndex, 0, elem);
      break;
    }
  }
})

console.log(columns);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple version

```js
Array.prototype.move = function(from, to) { this.splice(to, 0, this.splice(from, 1)[0]);};
const columns = [{ field: "name", type: "action", width: "settings.defaultColumnWidth", }, { field: "country", type: "action", width: "settings.defaultColumnWidth", }, { field: "phone", type: "action", width: "settings.defaultColumnWidth", }, { field: "email", type: "action", width: "settings.defaultColumnWidth", }, ];
const newOrder = [{ field: "country", oldIndex: 1, targetIndex: 2 } ];

newOrder.forEach(({ field, oldIndex, targetIndex }) => columns[oldIndex].field === field &&  columns.move(oldIndex,targetIndex));

console.log(columns)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with swapping technique.

```js
var settings = {
  defaultColumnWidth: 6
}

const columns=[
    {

        field: "name",
        type: "action",
        width: settings.defaultColumnWidth,
    },
    {
        field: "country",
        type: "action",
        width: settings.defaultColumnWidth,
      
    },
    {
        field: "phone",
        type: "action",
        width: settings.defaultColumnWidth,            
    },
    {
        field: "email",
        type: "action",
        width: settings.defaultColumnWidth,
    },
];
    
const newOrder = [
    {
        field: "country",
        oldIndex: 1,
        targetIndex: 2
    },
];

newOrder.forEach(function(order) {
  // swapping
  let temp = columns[ order['targetIndex'] ];
  columns[ order['targetIndex'] ] = columns[ order['oldIndex'] ];
  columns[ order['oldIndex'] ] = temp;
});

console.log( columns );
```